# How to return receiver and sender objects from User model

Tags: laravel-5

I'm building an app that has a section for user to user chatting. Naturally, I have a User model for the users table and a Chat model for the messages. In the Chat model, I have a belongsTo relationship with the User model and a corresponding hasMany relationship in the User model. The chats table have sender_id,  receiver_id & message columns.

**Models :**

```
class User extends Model {
    function chat(){
        return $this->hasMany(Chat::class);
    }
}

class Chat extends Model {
    function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /*** columns ***/
    /* sender_id
    * receiver_id
    * message
    */
}
```

I'm fine up till here. However, in the controller, when chat is saved in the table, I'm trying to return a response of the chat including the sender and receiver objects using the relationship I created in the Chat model but keeps getting only the sender object. I also tried using an accessor on the chat model like so:

`public function getReceiverAttribute(){
    $receiver = User::find($this->receiver_id)->first();
     return $receiver;
}`

Then appends this to the chat returned.
Yet I keep getting the sender object. I hope I'm able to clearly express the problem?
How do I get the receiver object?

NB: Pls I'm sending this from a mobile phone so it may not be properly formatted.

Comment: You mind showing us how you are saving the chat?

Comment: $chat = new Chat;                                                         $chat->sender_id = Auth::id();                                     $chat->receiver_id = $request->id;                            $chat->message = $request->message;                  $chat->save();

Comment: Then the answer i posted about separating ```sender``` and ```receiver``` should work for you. The model have to know in the relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to separate your relationships in the Chat model like below:

```
class Chat extends Model {
    /*function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }*/

    function sender(){
        //tell the relationship which column they are related on on that table
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sender_id'); 
    }

    function receiver(){
        //same applies here
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'receiver_id'); 
    }
}
```

Same goes for the user model

```
class User extends Model {
    /*function chat(){
        return $this->hasMany(Chat::class);
    }*/

    function senderChat(){
        return $this->hasMany(Chat::class, 'sender_id'); //specify in both models just in case
    }

    function receiverChat(){
        return $this->hasMany(Chat::class, 'receiver_id');
    }
}
```

I believe that will work for you, you will simply call those relationships from the `Chat` object